# Running tsc produces errors on React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I made couple of components with props passing, and it works fine, but when I run `yarn tsc` i get the following errors:

```
src/modules/BookingsPage/BookingsPage.tsx:52:14 - error TS2322: Type '{ data: { spBookingId: string; flightBooking: string; lastName: string; amount: string; date: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BookingsTable> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BookingsTable> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

52             <BookingsTable data={tableData}/>
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/BookingsPage/BookingsTable.tsx:44:37 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

44          <TableRow data={this.props.data}/>
                                       ~~~~

src/modules/BookingsPage/TableRow.tsx:16:11 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.

16     data: T[];
             ~


Found 3 errors.
```

Here is my code:

class `TableRow`:

```
type IData = {
    data: T[];
  }

export default class TableRow extends PureComponent<IData> {
    public render() {
      const {
        data
      } = this.props;
      const row = data.map((data: any) =>
      <TableBodyRow>
        <TableData>{data.spBookingId}</TableData>
        <TableData>{data.flightBooking}</TableData>
        <TableData>{data.lastName}</TableData>
        <TableData>{data.amount}</TableData>
        <TableData>{data.date}</TableData>
      </TableBodyRow>
      );
      return (
        <>{row}</>
      );
    }
  }
```

class BookingsTable

```
export default class BookingsTable extends PureComponent{

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render() {


    return (
      <TableContainer>
        <thead>
        <TableHeadRow>
          <TableHead>Booking id</TableHead>
          <TableHead>Flight Booking</TableHead>
          <TableHead>Last name</TableHead>
          <TableHead>Amount</TableHead>
          <TableHead>Date</TableHead>
        </TableHeadRow>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

         <TableRow data={this.props.data}/>  
        </tbody>

      </TableContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

And BookingPage:

```
const tableData = [
  {
    spBookingId: 'Y37HJ',
    flightBooking: 'HJK67',
    lastName: 'DOE',
    amount: '45e',
    date: '2019-02-12',
  },
  {
    spBookingId: 'Y37HJ',
    flightBooking: 'HJK67',
    lastName: 'Johnson',
    amount: '45e',
    date: '2019-02-12',
  },
  {
    spBookingId: 'Y37HJ',
    flightBooking: 'HJK67',
    lastName: 'Madsen',
    amount: '45e',
    date: '2019-02-12',
  },
  {
    spBookingId: 'Y37HJ',
    flightBooking: 'HJK67',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    amount: '45e',
    date: '2019-02-12',
  }
];

interface IbookingsPage{}

const BookingsPage: FunctionComponent<IbookingsPage> = () => {

    return (
        <>
           <Heading>
            <h3>Bookings</h3>   
          </Heading> 
            <BookingsTable data={tableData}/>

        </>
    );
}

export default BookingsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the following

```
type IData = {
    data: T[]; // Error: Cannot find `T`
}
```

The reason why you are getting the error is because you haven't added `T` as a generic parameter to `IData`.

## Fix

```
type IData<T> = {
    data: T[]; // OK 
}
```

Comment: Still getting two errors from above: error TS2339 and error TS2339